# R: find number of columns > 0 per row for a group of column names with a partial string match

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit, rowsum

I have a dataframe that resembles the following:

| ID | X | Y | A_1_l | A_2_m | B_1_n | B_2_l | C_1_m | C_2_n | C_3_l |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w | X | Y | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| x | X | Y | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| y | X | Y | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| z | X | Y | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 5 |

The first letter denotes a sample, the number a repetition and the second letter a batch. I am trying to find a count of the number of samples with at least one value > 0 for each ID and store these numbers in a list.

This is the desired result as a list that I can append to a an existing dataframe:

`0,1,3,3`

For a previous analysis I used `strsplit` to count the total number of samples per batch.

```
colsList <- colnames(df)
cols <- grep("_", colsList, value=TRUE)
splitList <- strsplit(cols, "_\\d_")
stats <-data.frame(t(as.data.frame.list(splitList)))
rownames(stats)<-NULL
names(stats)<-c("Sample", "Batch")
perSample <- aggregate(Sample ~ Batch, stats, 
                      function(x) length(unique(x))) # number of strains
```

And I was able to find the total number of columns with a value > 0 using `rowSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)] > 0)` but I cant seem to figure out how to combine the two to find the total number of samples > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First filter the data to keep only the numeric columns.

Use `split.default` to divide the data into groups so that you have all the `'A'` columns in one group, `'B'` in another and so on. Within each group return `TRUE` if a row has a single value which is greater than 0, `sum` all the values together from all the groups to get final count.

```
tmp <- Filter(is.numeric, df)

rowSums(sapply(split.default(tmp, sub('_.*', '', names(tmp))), 
        function(x) rowSums(x) > 0))

#[1] 0 1 3 3
```

Comment: I have other columns of strings that I should have included in my original dataframe. Is there an easy way to select only numeric columns in this example? I do not care about preserving the ID value or any other columns, I just need count results

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%  
    select(ID, where(is.numeric)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
    mutate(name = str_remove(name, "_.*")) %>% 
    group_by(ID, name) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value > 0), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value > 0))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID    value
  <chr> <int>
1 w         0
2 x         1
3 y         3
4 z         3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("w", "x", "y", "z"), X = c("X", "X", "X", 
"X"), Y = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), A_1_l = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), A_2_m = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 4L), B_1_n = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 5L), B_2_l = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 
6L), C_1_m = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), C_2_n = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), C_3_l = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```